# How insert element to generated request?

Tags: python, soap, onvif, zeep

I work with onvif wsdls.

And I want to send request "Subscribe" with Filter.
Filter contains TopicExpression. Request like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:b="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" 
xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
   <b:Subscribe>
     <b:ConsumerReference>
        <add:Address>http://10.1.50.11:8000</add:Address>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <add:ReferenceParameters>
           <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
        </add:ReferenceParameters>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <add:Metadata>
           <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
        </add:Metadata>
        <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
     </b:ConsumerReference>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <b:Filter>
        <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
        <wsnt:TopicExpression Dialect="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/topicExpression/ConcreteSet" xmlns:o2kvmd="http://www.o2kvmd.com/onvif-sdk/v1" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics">o2kvmd:Tele//.</wsnt:TopicExpression>
     </b:Filter>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <!--type: AbsoluteOrRelativeTimeType-->
     <b:InitialTerminationTime>PT60S</b:InitialTerminationTime>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <b:SubscriptionPolicy>
        <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
     </b:SubscriptionPolicy>
     <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
  </b:Subscribe>
```

In python code i can send request without Filter. Code like this:

```
notification = mycam.create_notification_service()
subscribe = notification.create_type('Subscribe')
obj = subscribe(ConsumerReference='http://10.1.50.11:8000',InitialTerminationTime='PT60S', Filter={})
notification.Subscribe(obj)
```

And request sent successfully

But I don't know how I can insert TopicExpression into Filter like in request above.
Tell me please, how I can this do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found is a great solution:

```
    topic_expression_type = zeep_client.get_type('TopicExpressionType')
    from zeep import xsd
    topic_exp = xsd.Element('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2}TopicExpression',xsd.ComplexType(topic_expression_type))
    subscribe = notification.create_type('Subscribe')
    any = xsd.AnyObject(topic_exp,topic_expression_type(_value_1=xsd.AnyObject(xsd.String(), 'o2kvmd:Telemetry//.'),Dialect='http://www.onvif.org/ver10/tev/topicExpression/ConcreteSet'))
    obj = subscribe(ConsumerReference='http://10.1.50.11:8000', InitialTerminationTime='PT60S', Filter={'_value_1': any})
    notification.Subscribe(obj)
```